# Bootstrap datetimepicker fills the date field before user choose it

Tags: bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I use datetimepicker to help the user choose the correct date in a form. I want the date field (id `#test`) to be empty before user make a choice.

Unfortunately when I set a `minDate` option like this:

```js
$('#test').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en-gb',
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: moment().add(1, 'day'),
});
```

the field `#test` is filled with the `minDate` before user do anything. This is wrong because I want the user actually click the `#test` field and choose the date so I can make AJAX request and check other things.

If the `minDate` option is not set the script behaves correctly.

Is there any way to tell the datetimepicker to not fill this field until the user actually do it himself?

If not, how to clear the #test field after the script fills it in?

Obviously I'd love to have something better than this:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
   $("#test").val('');
}, 200);
```

Ideally would be to use an event (if there is any) which can tell that the datetimepicker has been initialized. Something like `.done()` or `.then()` or `on('ready')`.

Answer (score 0):

As VincenzoC pointed out the solution is an option: useCurrent : false. So it sholud look like this:

```
$('#test').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'en-gb',
    format: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
    minDate: moment().add(1, 'day'),
    useCurrent : false,
});
```

Thank you VincenzoC!